# How to launch xamarin forms app with parameters

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Good morning everyone.

Please I am new to Xamarin forms.
What I want to achieve is I send a SMS text message to someone with pin code.  When they click on the link in the text message, my Xamarin forms app opens and extract the pin code that was sent.

Is there a way I can extract the parameters in C# Xamarin forms?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want launch parameters, what you are looking for is called [Deep Linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/deep-linking).

Tapping the link will then allow you to parse the URL in the app and you can extract whatever data you want from it.

Comment: Thank you very much David.  How do I do this?

Comment: This link had provided all steps ind details .